# Why does $∫{\frac{1+\log x}x}\,\mathrm dx$ not equal $\log x + \frac{(\log x)^2}2 + C?$

Tags: integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

When we assume that $$1+\log x = t,$$ then the integral becomes $$\log(1+\log x)+ C.$$
But when we assume that $$\log x = t,$$ the integral becomes
$$∫\frac1x + \frac{\log x}x\,\mathrm dx   \\
   \log x + \frac{(\log x)^2}2 + C.$$
Why the discrepancy?

Comment: Wouldn't your first integral then be $\int t dt = t^2/2+C$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

If you do the substitution $t=1+\log{x}$, the integral becomes$$\int t dt=\frac{1}{2}t^2+C=\frac{1}{2}(1+\log{x})^2+C=\frac{1}{2}(\log{x})^2+\log{x}+\frac{1}{2}+C$$
Combining $\frac{1}{2}$ and C into a new arbitrary constant gives you the same result